# emacs - show the current file in other frame

Tags: emacs, ido

I want to do something similar to `iswitchb-buffer-other-frame`
except, set the file name programmatically to be the current frame.
(with `iswitchb-buffer-other-frame` you have to chose the file interactively)

If iswitchb is obsolete, can I achieve that with `ido-mode` or another package (or straight Lisp)?

How can I do that?

---

EDIT

Based on the answer of [@pickle-rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415684/pickle-rick) I adjusted the code to my needs.

- I need to use `switch-to-buffer-other-window` instead of `switch-to-buffer-other-frame`.
  I'm not sure why...
  In my setting, I have 2 frames - each frame has a single window, and I need to move the current buffer to the other frame.
  But it works!
- Also, I populate the original frame with an arbitrary buffer (`*scratch*`) (to prevent showing the original buffer in the original frame)

Here is my adjusted code:

```
(defun my-switch-buffer-other-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window (current-buffer))
  (other-frame 1)
  (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")
  (other-frame 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ido equivalent is `ido-switch-buffer-other-frame`, which prompts for interactive selection as well. Here is a simple modification to avoid the prompting, and use the current buffer instead,

```
(defun my-switch-buffer-other-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-frame (current-buffer)))
```